# (HTML/CSS) How do I repeat items like on Google or Reddit?

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML/CSS right now and am trying to create a clone of reddit.com as a learning exercise. On a website like reddit or google there are repeating "items" that consist of a header, maybe an icon, and a short description. Using HTML and CSS I am able to reproduce one of these items, but my question is how to make a bunch of these without copying and pasting. I am assuming there is a way, but am unsure. Thanks for any help!

Comment: this can be done dynamically with jquery. try to learn jquery and `.append()` in jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have a lot of possiblities - if you really want to "only" demo something for learning purpose you should probably go with jquery.

1. you need to insert the jquery libary either use a hosted one or download one and include the script into you code
2. you can then use a loop and for example .append() to append elements to another alement

example (html)

```
<ul class="post"></ul>
```

example (js/jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i= 0; i < 10; i++) {
       $('.post').append('<li>This is a post with number ' + i + '</li>');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Other Ideas:

- if it shouldn't be a demo, but a more like a working prototype which actually does what reddit does you will probably need to go beyond html & css and at least add php or something similar. You could then use a database with testdata and loop over the results to append them

Comment: I will look into jquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The *real* answer would be some type of server script such as PHP with a looping statement. This is a little more in depth of an answer than you may have originally expected, but it will be good way to branch out into other languages possibly. Here would be an example code snippet of PHP code.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    echo '
    <section class="post">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h3>Sub-Title</h3>
        <p>Here is a short description</p>
    </section>';
}
?>
```

This would output the part after "echo" 10 times because it would loop that over and over.

Just food for thought when you get further into web development. Good luck man! And enjoy the journey. Let me know if you'd want a more in depth example.

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not have the concept of variable which you can use it later. HTML also do not have functions /methods to be used, thus for your purpose you got to use JavaScript/jQuery/Nodejs to replicate the dom elements.

Though there is a background repeat property in css, which you use to repeat the background for any element.

`background-repeat: repeat-y;`
`background-repeat: repeat-x;`
`background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Ref: - [CSS Background Repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Comment: Just how does this answer to anything the OP asked?

Comment: As he said that he is learning html/css so answering him with say jquery code doesn't makes much sense as he wont be getting into that straight away. So I conveyed him the fact about what html/css could and couldn't do.